# Smart cast variable in lambda kotlin workaround

Tags: android, variables, lambda, casting, kotlin

I have past a lambda today that has a variable which is of unknown type , and inside the when..is condition , the variable can't smart cast to the type in the is condition ... it gives that it is impossible since the variable is a Public Api , is there a workaround to this ?

[image]

Comment: Please add your code snipped in the text form, so that it can be copy-pasted. I had to retype you code to answer you question, which was not that enjoyable.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a more convenient `onBind` extension function which has `item`, `view`, etc. passed to the lambda instead of receiving an `ItemViewTypePosition`:

```
inline fun LastAdapter.Builder.onBind(crossinline f: (item: Any, view: View, type: Int, position: Int) -> Unit): LastAdapter.Builder {
    return onBindListener(object : OnBindListener {
        override fun onBind(item: Any, view: View, type: Int, position: Int) {
            f(item, view, type, position)
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
builder.onBind { item, view, type, position ->
    when (item) {
        is Product -> view.number_sold.text = item.price.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple workaround which is defining a val to equal the wanted variable and use that instead like so ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to make the cast yourself:

```
.onBind {
    when(item) {
        is Product -> view.number_sold_text = (item as Product).price.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: It becomes irritating when you have multiple children objects , so i wen with that